# Substitution of list elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of string elements:

```
  lis = {{"Abc","Def"},{"Ghi","Abc"},{"Mno","Pqrs"}};

  abbrPool = {{"Abc","A"},{"Mno","M"}};
```

I would like to replace certain elements in the first list with the matching second elements from the second list, to give:

```
  res = {{"A","Def"},{"Ghi","A"},{"M","Pqrs"}}
```

I can do this by brute force using Cases/DeleteCases, but wonder if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html).

```
lis /. Rule @@@ abbrPool
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ReplaceAt[MapApply[Rule] @ abbrPool, {All, 1}] @ lis
```

{{"A", "Def"}, {"Ghi", "Abc"}, {"M", "Pqrs"}}

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `AssociationThread` and `Lookup`:

```
Map[Lookup[AssociationThread @@ Transpose[abbrPool], #, #] &, lis, {2}] === res

(*True*)
```

Or using `Replace`:

```
Replace[lis, Rule @@@ abbrPool, {2}] === res

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
lis = {{"Abc", "Def"}, {"Ghi", "Abc"}, {"Mno", "Pqrs"}};
abbrPool = {{"Abc", "A"}, {"Mno", "M"}};

lut = Rule @@@ abbrPool
Map[Lookup[lut, #, #] &, lis, {2}]
```

> {{"A", "Def"}, {"Ghi", "A"}, {"M", "Pqrs"}}